# how to count failure occurrences in a column using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to use python's pandas to tabulate the test result in a csv format. The result could be "passsed" or sometime "failed". After I

```
    import python as pd,my code is:
    df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
    pass_res =df['Status'].value_counts()['passed']
    fail_res =df['Status'].value_counts()['failed']
```

this code will work if there IS a case of fail. However, when there is no failure, the last line of code will cause an error. How do check, if there is a failure, then I will execute my last line.

Comment: Run `value_counts()` once instead of twice, which is wasteful.  Save the result.  Now you can say `if 'failed' in results:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also add a `CategoricalDType` as `value_counts` returns all observed:

```
# sample
df = pd.DataFrame({'Status': ['passed']*5 + ['other']*3})

status = pd.CategoricalDtype(['passed', 'failed'], ordered=True)
passed, failed = df['Status'].astype(status).value_counts().sort_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> passed
5

>>> failed
0

>>> df['Status'].astype(status).value_counts().sort_index()
Status
passed    5
failed    0
Name: count, dtype: int64

>>> df
   Status
0  passed
1  passed
2  passed
3  passed
4  passed
5   other
6   other
7   other
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets use `Series.get` to yank the value if found otherwise return 0

```
s = df['Status'].value_counts()

passed = s.get('passed', 0)
failed = s.get('failed', 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Corralien's but with [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
df['Status'].value_counts(sort=False).reindex(['passed', 'failed'], fill_value=0)
```

Defining the variables in one shot:

```
passed, failed = (df['Status'].value_counts(sort=False)
                  .reindex(['passed', 'failed'], fill_value=0)
                 )
```

Comment: I think it's an existing answer ;)